# Calculating end of quarter into next year returns 2 values

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to return a date for each end of quarter. I use it to create users and set expire dates. For example, if the currently month is December, the end of the quarter will be set to Q1 of 2022.

Here is my function:

```
Function QuarterEnd($today) {
    $year = $today.year
    $month = $today.month

    if ($month -eq 12) {
        $year + 1
    }

    Switch ($month) {
        1  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-03-31T00:00:00") }
        2  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-03-31T00:00:00") }
        3  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-06-30T00:00:00") }
        4  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-06-30T00:00:00") }
        5  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-06-30T00:00:00") }
        6  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-09-30T00:00:00") }
        7  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-09-30T00:00:00") }
        8  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-09-30T00:00:00") }
        9  { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-12-31T00:00:00") }
        10 { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-12-31T00:00:00") }
        11 { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-12-31T00:00:00") }
        12 { $(Get-Date -Date "$year-03-31T00:00:00") }
    }
}
```

Then I simply call it:

`. .\quarterdate.ps1; QuarterEnd $(Get-Date)`

The output I get:

```
PS . .\quarterdate.ps1; QuarterEnd $(Get-Date)
2022
20210331
```

My issue is that when I reach this last quarter, it outputs 2022 first and then the date below it.

How do I replace that output to show the correct date? It should be `20210331`.

For example, if I give it a "regular" date which isn't the end of the year, everything looks good:

```
. .\quarterdate.ps1; QuarterEnd $(Get-Date -date "2022-03-31")
20220630
```

Thanks

Comment: This: `$year + 1` writes the next year to the output. Perhaps you meant `$year = $year + 1`?

Comment: thanks, what would be the correct way to add one year in case the next quarter is march of next year?

Comment: You add 1 to the year, and set month to 1, so the above statement change + this: `$month = 1`

Comment: Thank you, feel free to comment these 2 changes and I'll accept it as an answer :)

Comment: `12 { $(Get-Date -Date "$($year+1)-03-31T00:00:00") }` should suffice (omitting all the `if ($month -eq 12) { … }`).